# Navigation Drawer to store responses and passes to Main Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to create a Navigation Drawer which have **checkboxes** but I want to listen only to the ***button*** added in drawer to ***store*** all checkboxes ***checked*** ***responses*** in an array and on button press this drawer will be **closed**.

So **goal** is to have a **Navigation Drawer** but I don't want to ***navigate*** anywhere instead store all responses of checkboxes from drawer and get it into an activity.

Answer (score 0):

try using broadcast receivers[Broadcast reciver documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: On Sliding menu ? My problem is how to add checkboxes and listen to the button which will save all responses in an array

Comment: you drawer will contain a fragment try using checkboxes in its layout

Comment: Shall I Update my question to give you overview what I have done until now?